# event based socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, select

when the call to select statement returns , we check for the active file descriptors to process the multiple client's request.

```
select(maxfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

That , is select command monitors the file descriptors in the readfds set.  My Question is , while at the time of processing the client's request , more new connections arrives at the listening socket , how would the program capture those new connections ?

Comment: You have to use Threads.

Comment: It wouldn't until it's finished processing the current connection. Of course, that's assuming you're just using one thread/process.

Comment: @Abhishek Sagar: you have asked 10 questions but didn't accept a single answer. Please mark answers as accepted if they solved your problem.

Comment: @DanielKozar , it means , i should use a thread to process the client(s) request , while main thread takes care of select call ? Well , if that is the case then , read_set will be the shared variable between main and the other thread , therefore , need to use mutexes for correct working of the program ?

Comment: @nightcracker , ok i 'll take care of that.

Comment: @DanielKozar , also , then how is then it is called "Concurrent programming" when select call fails to capture incoming connections while processing client's request !!

Answer (score 3):

You learn about that if you monitor the server socket in the readfd set of select(). Select indicating a server socket as readable, means there's a connection waiting, so you can accept() it.

```
...
FD_SET(server_sock, &readfds);

select(maxfd + 1,&readfds,NULL,NULL,NULL); 
if(FD_ISSET(server_sock, &readfds)) {
    int new_client = accept(server_socket, ... );
    //add the new client to descriptors to monitor, etc..
```

(Note that the OS does the initial TCP handshake and establishes a connection, accept() just makes the connection available for your program)